# How to match regular expression for below string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

Below string I need to compare conditional operator. So only if  81.1.4_r4345 doing some operation or else matching with “done” then execute some operation.

```
  vasanth-releases_81.1.4_r4345.tar.gz

     vasanth-releases-done.tar.gz
  

If [[ $var == ‘vasanth-releases_{0-9}_{0-9}.tar.gz ]] ; then 
    echo ‘True’
Elsif [[ $var  == ‘Vasanth-releases-{a-z}.tar.gz ]]; then 
    echo ‘False’
else 
    echo ‘default’
fi
```

Above try not working expected. So need regex format for this two files. Could you please help on this

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please edit it.

Comment: Updated expected @Devon

Comment: Are you actually using "smart quotes" in your expression? Do you get any error messages? Please note that the shell is case-sensitive, so `If` with uppercase `I` should certainly throw an error. Also `Elsif` is wrong. I would recommend running your script through [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to guard against this kind of error.

Comment: Paste your code to https://www.shellcheck.net/ and consider the errors and comments it gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

var="vasanth-releases_81.1.4_r4345.tar.gz"
if [[ $var =~ ^vasanth-releases_[0-9.]+_r[0-9]+\.tar\.gz$ ]]; then
    echo ‘True’
elif [[ $var  =~ ^vasanth-releases-[a-z]+\.tar\.gz$ ]]; then
    echo ‘False’
else
    echo ‘default’
fi

var="vasanth-releases-done.tar.gz"
if [[ $var =~ ^vasanth-releases_[0-9.]+_r[0-9]+\.tar\.gz$ ]]; then
    echo ‘True’
elif [[ $var =~ ^vasanth-releases-[a-z]+\.tar\.gz$ ]]; then
    echo ‘False’
else
    echo ‘default’
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your ultimate end goal is but I can point out some issues with your code:

1. You should not use capitals in shell commands or builtins so `If` should be `if`
2. `elsif` is not valid, it should be `elif`
3. You are using "smart quotes" likely due to being copied out of a word processor not suited for code editing.
4. Even if the smart quotes are changed to regular quotes you are opening a single quote in the first conditional and not closing it again until the second conditional.
5. In bash you need to use the `=~` operator for regex comparisons and not the `==` operator.
6. The curly bracket doesn't do what you are trying to accomplish in regex, you need to use `[0-9]` and `[a-z]` to match any character in those ranges.
7. Even if you fixed the brackets in your regex they still wouldn't match your file.  You can try building the proper regex using regex101.com but be aware that bash does extended regular expressions which is not an available option on regex101, pcre is close but you will find some things that are not cross compatible.

Comment: `[[ var == pattern ]]` in bash (like in ksh) does wildcard/glob (not regexp) pattern matching, not exact comparison.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: thanks